# Why rand() %max+min formula is not giving desired output in range between (1000 to 1112)?

Tags: c

// This is the code its part of my college assignment

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>// header file for rand and srand function
    #include <time.h>
    int main()
    {
        srand(time(0)); //  time is used for different values
        int result = rand() % 1112 + 1000; // 1112 is max value & 1000 is min value. Also This formula worked in range between (-999 to 999)
        printf("%d", result);
        return 0;
    }
Output:
1702
1810 and so on...
```

I noticed this during my college assignment...

Comment: What do you expect the range of `rand() % 1112` to be?

Comment: The formula really worked for -999 to 999? Were positive values generated?

Comment: Aside: [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) has appropriate parameters

Comment: Note that C and C++ are vastly different programming languages.  There is no "C/C++" language.

Comment: I have edited it was tagged unintentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. you need to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381843/generate-random-number-in-range-min-max/29382078)

```
result = min + rand() %(max+1 - min);
```

in your case

```
result = rand() % (1112 + 1 - 1000 ) + 1000;
```

what you have wrote will generate numbers from 0 to 1111 then it will add another 1000 to the generated number ..

Answer (score 2):

`rand() % 1112` may become values in the range 0 to 1111.

You should do `rand() % (1112 - 1000 + 1) + 1000` because the offset from 1000 should be in the range 0 to `1112 - 1000`.

Comment: ...because the offset from 1000 should be in the range 0 to 1112 - 1000. I am not getting this?? please explain. I will be thankful to you

Comment: @captainanas "the offset from 1000 should be in the range 0 to 1112 - 1000" means the offset from 1000 should be in the range 0 to 112. So adding the offset to 1000 produces a number in the range 1000 to 1112 as required.

Comment: @IanAbbott Got it.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2021 so use C++11 solution: [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

```cpp
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distrib(1000, 1112);
    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << distrib(gen) << '\n';
```

Here is [nice explanation](https://youtu.be/LDPMpc-ENqY) why and how to use it

Comment: Dear C was the part of the assignment so I was just checking the formula.

Comment: I've found your question by `C++` tag. So yes my answer is valid for C++ only.

Comment: xD) No problem sir.